# Tensorflow computing an aggregate function over lots of data in tfrecord format

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I have a very large dataset stored in chunks of 5000 across several tfrecord files. Together all of these records are way larger than my RAM. What I would like to do is sample from N = 0.05 * TOTAL_SIZE random indexes in the dataset and compute the mean and std deviation to normalize my data.

If it wasn't for the dataset size this would be easy, but I run out of memory even when I try and compute a sum of all the tensors I'm interested in.

```
# NOTE: count is computed ahead of time by looping over all the tfrecord entries

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    sample_size = int(count * 0.05)
    random_indexes = set(np.random.randint(low=0, high=count, size=sample_size))
    stat_graph = tf.Graph()
    with tf.Session(graph=stat_graph) as sess:
        val_sum = np.zeros(shape=(180, 2050))
        for file in files:
            print("Reading from file: %s" % file)
            for record in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(file):
                features = tf.parse_single_example(
                    record,
                    features={
                        "val": tf.FixedLenFeature((180, 2050), tf.float32),
                    })
                if index in random_indexes:
                    val_sum += features["val"].eval(session=sess)
                index += 1
        val_mean = val_sum / sample_size
```

What is the right way to compute some aggregate function, i.e. mean and/or standard deviation, over a tfrecord dataset?

Comment: The code seems like it should work, where do you get an error?

Comment: I don't get any errors from my code. The process gets killed when it uses up all my memory. I watch in htop as my memory steadily climbs until it gets up around 63 GB and then the process is killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that tf.parse_single_example adds a new tensor to the graph every time it's called.  Instead of the above, you should feed the string with a placeholder:

```
...
record_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
features = tf.parse_single_example(
    record_placeholder,
    features={
        "val": tf.FixedLenFeature((180, 2050), tf.float32),
    })
for record in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(file):
...
val_sum += features["val"].eval(feed_dict={record_placeholder: record}, session=sess)
```

Let me know if this works since I have no way of testing it.

Comment: I assume that record_placeholder is being passe to tf.parse_single_example instead of record?

Comment: Yep!  It's actually supposed to take a tensor.  The string you plug in just gets automatically promoted to one.

Comment: And actually thinking about it, you can put the first two lines on the outside of the first for loop as well, it only needs to be created once.  You can think of running that line as placing that operation in the graph and then it gets run whenever you use `.eval()`

Comment: How does tensorflow know to fill in the right value for record_placeholder though? It seems like there should be some explicit mapping between record_placeholder and record prior to accessing the features dictionary.

Comment: Check the last line of code I posted - the feed dict maps the record string to the tensor.  Edit: You might have missed it cause I edited it in a while ago - sorry!

Comment: Got it, before reading it I got an error due to not including the feed_dict and came to the same conclusion :). Lets see how it goes now...

Comment: That did it! Thanks for your help.